# Why do different materials absorb and reflect different wavelengths of light?

Tags: visible-light

How so are different pigments differently coloured?

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with the details of the electronic orbital structure encircling the various parts of the pigment molecule, and the bonds between the atoms in the molecule. depending on the energy level occupied by a given electron in a certain part of the molecule and the availability of a higher energy level into which that electron might be promoted, it is possible to get that energy level difference to coincide with that of an incoming photon of light that is within the visible spectrum. When this happens, that particular wavelength of light will be absorbed by the molecule either by exciting that susceptible electron or by exciting a resonance in one of the interatomic bonds, while all other wavelengths are unaffected. the unaffected wavelengths get scattered off the surface of the pigment particle and some of those will make it into your eye.

The color you see is then that of white light (all colors mixed together) minus the absorbed color. For example, if reddish light gets absorbed, the pigment looks greenish to your eye.

Answer (score -1):

It's a cause of electron Transition from different energy levels.
Understanding from an elementary part of this:
BOHR'S HYDROGEN SPECTRUM
1. Here an electron makes transition from higher orbital to lower orbital, it's gives out energy in form of light. As these energy levels are fixed we see particular amount of energy released and thus a particular wavelength of light. The relation given by:
E=hv (v= frequency of light radiated).
2. The same is for energy absorbtion.